# Batch editing of records, with multiple functions

Tags: php, javascript, html, batch-file, edit

I would like an administrator to be able to batch edit records.  Ideally, I want the admin to be able to delete records, or toggle several values on/off.  I've figured out I can display the records inside a form and put checkboxes by each to collect an array of ids.  The submit button lets me collect the id array of checked records and send them to the server for processing as follows:

html:

```
<form="batchprocess.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="'.$id.'">RECORD<input type="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

server/php:

```
$sql = "delete from tbl where id IN (implode(REQUEST['record']))";
```

This works for one function such as delete.

My problem is I cannot figure out how to have several buttons that do different administrative things, ie delete, toggle show, toggle hide etc.  If it were possible in html to have different buttons that do different things, ie a submit button that includes a unique value in it, then I could just use html but as far as I know multiple differing submit buttons in a form is not possible.

Javascript lets you have multiple buttons, but I don't know how to read the checkbox user input in javascript.

FYI, I imagine the batch of records per page would be about 20.  Also don't want to have other field in form that says delete/show/hide or something to that effect for reasons of a clean U/I.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Please try to think of more descriptive title. Title is the "door" to your question and such a bad title is really a bad start, even if the question itself is good.

Comment: Just so you know, don't put `$_REQUEST` inside a SQL query - you'll get a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple submit buttons in a form - the submitted button sets the element's name key to the value (caption) of the button. "a submit button that has a switch in it" - I'm not sure what you mean there. Would you clarify that part of the text (by editing your question)?

Comment: Sorry, left out title.  Yes, the sql statement is shorthand.

Comment: Ok, so something like <input type="submit" id="del" value= "Delete"><input type="submit" id="show" value= "Show Record"><input type="submit" id="hide" value= "Hide Record"> with some if then logic on server side?

Comment: Yes, although if you've got lots of rows, it could be del_1, show_1, hide_1, and then repeated for every primary key you're showing. Then you just need to scan your `$_POST` array for keys matching a regex, and so long as its value is non-null, you know which one was pressed.